# Array of stringed objects. Need to de string them

Tags: arrays, angular, object, for-loop, pdfmake

I have an array of strings that are actually objects.

```
  buildTaskMatrix(pages) {
let allTasks = [];
for (let i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
  const page = pages[i];
  for (let j = 0; j < page.tasks.length; j++) {
    const task = page.tasks[j];
    allTasks.push(
      `[{ text: task.panelName, fontSize: 5, colSpan: 2 },
      {},
      { text: task.panelQty },
      { text: task.panelWidth + 'x' + task.panelHeight },
      { text: task.substrateName, fontSize: 5, colSpan: 2 },
      {},
      { text: task.producingBranch, fontSize: 5, colSpan: 2 },
      {},
      { text: task.specialInstructions, fontSize: 5, colSpan: 3 },
      {},
      {}]`
    );
    // const test = allTasks[j][0].replace('"', '');
    // const test2 = test.slice(0, -1);
  }
}
return allTasks;
```

}

I am trying to either replace the strings or find another solution to add these to my PDFmake object that needs to be in the below format.

```
[
        { text: '2', style: 'header', fontSize: 5, colSpan: 2 },
        {},
        { text: 'Qty', style: 'header', fontSize: 5 },
        { text: 'Size', style: 'header', fontSize: 5 },
        { text: 'Substrate', style: 'header', fontSize: 5, colSpan: 2 },
        {},
        { text: 'Prod City', style: 'header', fontSize: 5, colSpan: 2 },
        {},
        { text: 'Notes', style: 'header', fontSize: 5, colSpan: 3 },
        {},
        {}
      ],
```

I have tried..

```
taskMatrix[0].replace('"', '')
```

which does not seem to work.

Arrays don't hold multiple objects in a position but that would be the ideal solution for me. My thoughts are I am approaching this the wrong way and really hope someone has an idea what I am doing wrong

Comment: You don't have an array of strings which are actually objects, you have an array of strings. And because you have used an array of strings you now require a custom string parser to turn the string into an object you can use. The use case for this circular logic is difficult to understand. Why not just push the objects in the first place?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. My approach was super dumb

Comment: So let's work through it. But first, can you explain why `style` shows up in the `to be` version but is not present in the `as is` version?

Answer (score 0):

You should either push object directly into the array, or if you really need strings for whatever reason, use JSON.parse() to convert a string of JSON formatted text into a Javacript object. You would need to parameter the string properly though, and make sure the text fields are double-quoted.